# Rendering a Table of Data in React from JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, jsx

I am trying to create a React component that renders a table of data from a JavaScript object `pixarMovies` that I initially set the state of. I would like to render a table of the movie data with movies sorted chronologically by date (I've attached [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5swT.png) of what I'm trying to do that I created in HTML). How might one accomplish this?

This component is separate from `App.js`, and I will include it in a different component. I would like the table to adjust accordingly to the state (to account for the addition and removal of movies), as well as be able to apply `onClick` functions to the buttons.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class PixarMovies extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pixarMovies: [
            {
                title: "Cars",
                date: "2006-06-09",
                budget: "$120 million",
            },
            {
                title: "Toy Story",
                date: "1995-11-05",
                budget: "$30 million",
            },
            {
                title: "Ratatouille",
                date: "2007-06-29",
                budget: "$150 million",
            },
            {
                title: "The Incredibles",
                date: "2004-11-05",
                budget: "$92 million"
            }
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Pixar Movies</h1>
                {/* Insert Table here */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Iterate over the array and create a table row for each object.

Comment: How would I create a table row for each object in React?

Comment: objectArray.map(obj => <tr><td>{obj.someProperty}</td></tr>)

Comment: How would I loop through this map to render the data in my table?

Comment: You mean how to iterate over an object to render a cell for each property?

Comment: Yes. To create the table and button elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like there are a couple of pieces here, so let's take a look at each of them.

**Sorting chronologically by date**: Javascript arrays have a sort function that looks like this: `myArray.sort()`. You can pass a function to the `.sort` call to use whatever field you want. So maybe something like this for you:

```
const sortedPixarMovies = this.state.pixarMovies.sort((movA, movB) => new Date(movA.date) - new Date(movB.date));
```

**Rendering a table**: There are a bunch of ways to render a table in React. I'd recommend looking at some 3rd party components that will make rendering a table quite simple and effortless. If you want to build one yourself, take a look at something like [this guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-tables-in-react-part-one--cms-29682). A quick google of "render a table in react" should give you all the information you need.

**Table should adjust according to state**: This should happen automatically. Every time your component's state changes, your component will re-render, so it will re-render the table with the new data.

**Apply onClick functions to buttons**: I don't see any buttons in your code, but onClick functions work in react pretty much like they would in anything else. Define a function on your component, then pass it to the button. For example:

The function:

```
myOnChangeFunc = (newValue) => {
  this.setState({ myField: newValue });
}
```

And then the button:

```
<button onChange={ this.myOnChangeFunc }>My Button</button>
```

---

**Responding to question below**

If you're using a 3rd party component, usually you want to pass your data in as a prop. So your render function might look something like:

```
render() {
  const myFormattedData = this.state.data.map... (formatted);
  return <ThirdPartyComponent data = { myFormattedData } />;
}
```

If you're doing it yourself, you can map the data in your render function. Here's a super simple example of how you would render a list:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      { this.state.listData.map((d) => <li key={ d.id }>{ d.value }</li>) }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Is there a way to pass the data from the JavaScript array and turn it into HTML code to be rendered in React?

Comment: Yep, totally. Answered above so I can show examples.

Comment: Ah I figured it out now! Thanks!